# groupby with leap years

Tags: python, group-by, python-xarray

First the overall objective: I have a global daily mean sea surface temperature array:

```
>>> sst
<xarray.DataArray 'sst' (time: 10957, lat: 720, lon: 1440)>
dask.array<rechunk-merge, shape=(10957, 720, 1440), dtype=float32, chunksize=(10957, 1, 1), 
chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 ... 359.375 359.625 359.875
  * lat      (lat) float32 -89.875 -89.625 -89.375 ... 89.375 89.625 89.875
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1989-01-01 1989-01-02 ... 2018-12-31
Attributes:
    long_name:    Daily Sea Surface Temperature
```

What I need to find are heatwaves, defined as "a period of 5 or more days in which the temperature at a given location is above the 90th percentile for that location and day in the year."

This definition wants me to compare each date to the same date of the other years, so I can't just use `time.dayofyear` but that's okay. I've created a new array `monthday`:

```
>>> monthday = xr.DataArray(
>>>     sst.time.dt.month*100+sst.time.dt.day, 
>>>     name='monthday', dims='time', coords={'time':sst['time']}
>>> )
>>> sst['monthday'] = monthday
```

And I can now groupby `monthday`

My problem at the moment is the leap years. As you can see, there are only 7 leap years in this dataset, and getting a 90th percentile from just 7 values makes little sense.

So to calculate the 90th percentile for Feb. 29th it was decided that for non-leap years, we should use the average of Feb 28th and Mar 1st.

Short of creating a new array, with dimensions `(year, monthday)` for each horizontal gridpoint, then manually filling in those values, and finally running a groupby and percentile, I don't know what to do.

Any suggestions to make it more elegantly (and preferably a method to preserve the ability to use `dask` for parallelisation)?

Thanks

Comment: Disclaimer: New to Python and still learning. However, I wanted to see if this would work. The array for 7 years would be 7 x 365. Wouldn't you be able to redo the array as 7 x 366, you move 60th thru 365th to 61th thru 366th, then repopulate 60th position with avg of 59th and 61st. Not sure if that's what you referred to "creating new array with dimensions (year, monthday)" is the same thing.  Also, this was posted 8 months ago. Did you figure out a logic for this. curious :)